# Lockdown Workstation to Protect software

Tags: windows-10, security

TLDR: I need to prevent someone from being able to copy a file off a kiosk-like computer if they plug in a keyboard and mouse, I could potentially disable all keyboard and mouse input if there is a way to feasibly do that, and if that would not prevent me from remotely accessing the hardware to reconfigure it.

Full details:

Ok, I don't know if this is the right place to ask this question, but here is what I have, and what I want to do.

I wrote a piece of software that our company wants to sell, I have the software licensed using some hardware identifiers on machines that we own and that we are LEASING to our customers.

The software is specifically for digital signage, and my boss want's me to make sure that the software cannot be copied from the computer

Because of the nature of the software the system has to automatically login and open the software to start displaying the digital media, I've encrypted the drive with bitlocker using the built in TPM, locked down the BIOS using a password and enabled secure boot, and there are no credentials to access the software from the network.

But, if someone simply plugs in a usb mouse and keyboard they can have full access to the machine since it's already logged in.

I replaced the windows shell with our watchdog program that monitors the digital signage software and receives network commands to reconfigure the display / restart the software when needed, and the software itself runs in full screen mode without an easy way to close it.

I could prevent USB drives from being used via a local GPO, I could disable keyboard/mouse input (if there is a way to do that) but that might cause problems later if I need to use it, I could try and prevent any and all ways to access files on the PC since I have full control over windows and replaced the shell, but that seems like a futile effort.

Whats the best way, if any, to accomplish this?

Comment: You can disable USB devices that are not specifically allowed.  But an Administrator on the machine can allow any device.  If somebody wanted to mount the storage device on another system all they would need is the password to BitLocker or simply disable it.

Comment: Indeed, I can not-provide an administrator account, since the box is ours, and the bitlocker password is stored in TPM so that should be secure. I'll look into how to selectively disable USB devices, that may fit the bill here. Thank you.